# Illustrator: how to crop artwork and save as SVG?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export, canvas

I just need to crop half size of image like this. But I have no experience with svg format. I tried adjusting canvas size manual but no luck. Should I select this area and paste in to new file like photoshop? or any perfect way of doing this? I need it to save as SVG format.

[image]

Comment: Can you not merely reduce that large field of green?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and adjust canvas size to your liking
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to 'Save as', choose SVG format and tick 'Use Artboards'

Comment: This doesn't seem to dispense with the SVG data that was originally there. Opening the SVG file and adjusting the `viewBox` will show that the rest of the image data is still present - which is no good if you're expecting file-size to reduce.